# Merge 2 sorted arrays into vector c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, merge, function-definition

Hi I'm trying to merge 2 sorted array into a vector.

The following is my code. I believe that I am using the correct algorithm however, when I print the vector out its only prints 1,2.

Can someone please take a look at my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> merge(int arr1[],int arr2[])
{
    int arr1size = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
    int arr2size = sizeof(arr2) / sizeof(arr2[0]);
    vector<int> arr3;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i<arr1size && j<arr2size)
    {
        if(arr1[i] <= arr2[j])
        {
            arr3.push_back(arr1[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr3.push_back(arr2[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    while(i<arr1size)
    {
        arr3.push_back(arr1[i]);
        i++;
    }
    while(j<arr2size)
    {
        arr3.push_back(arr2[j]);
        j++;
    }
    return arr3;
}
int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {1, 3, 5, 7};
    int arr2[] = {2, 4, 6, 8};
    vector<int> arr3;
    arr3 = merge(arr1,arr2);
    for(int i=0;i<arr3.size();i++)
    {
        cout << arr3[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could check the obtained value here: `int arr1size = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);`. A classical mistake. At this point `arr1[]` is a pointer only, not an array. You must provide the function with the sizes, or use `std::vector`

Comment: You're using the correct code to print the array, so if the printed output is not as expected, you have computed the wrong results. Anyhow, the thing you're missing is just a skill and that is to step through code with a debugger. There are video tutorials on the web which will demonstrate this for whatever IDE you use. Using a debugger makes it really easy to fix this without any help from others.

Comment: @damien hmm, look like you are right. I moved arr1size and arr2size calculations to main and pass it as a parameter and it was displaying the right values. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function parameter that has an array type is adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the array element type. That is this function declaration

```
vector<int> merge(int arr1[],int arr2[]);
```

is adjusted by the compiler to the declaration

```
vector<int> merge(int *arr1, int *arr2);
```

On the other hand, arrays used as function arguments are converted implicitly to pointers to their first elements. That is this function call

```
merge(arr1,arr2)
```

is equivalent to the following function call

```
merge( &arr1[0], &arr2[0] )
```

Hence within the function these declarations

```
int arr1size = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
int arr2size = sizeof(arr2) / sizeof(arr2[0]);
```

are in turn equivalent to

```
int arr1size = sizeof( int * ) / sizeof( int );
int arr2size = sizeof( int * ) / sizeof( int );
```

and depending on sizes of objects of the type `int *` and `int` the initializing expressions are evaluated either to `2` or `1`. That is they do not yield the numbers of elements in the arrays used as function arguments.

Moreover you should use the type `size_t` instead of the type `int` because the operator sizeof returns a value of the type `size_t`.

Also the function parameters should have the qualifier `const` because the arrays are not changed within the function.

You need explicitly to pass numbers of elements in each array.

So the function declaration will look like

```
std::vector<int> merge( const int arr1[], size_t n1, const int arr2[], size_t n2 );
```

Pay attention that it is inefficient to use a vector without initially reserving enough space for added elements.

In general you should use a qualified name of the function `merge`.

The function can look the following as it is shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> merge( const int arr1[], size_t n1, const int arr2[], size_t n2 )
{
    std::vector<int> arr3;
    arr3.reserve( n1 + n2 );
    
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    
    while ( i < n1 && j < n2 )
    {
        if( arr2[j] < arr1[i] )
        {
            arr3.push_back( arr2[j] );
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr3.push_back( arr1[i] );
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    while ( i < n1 )
    {
        arr3.push_back( arr1[i] );
        i++;
    }
    
    while ( j < n2 )
    {
        arr3.push_back( arr2[j] );
        j++;
    }
    
    return arr3;
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {1, 3, 5, 7};
    int arr2[] = {2, 4, 6, 8};
    const size_t N1 = sizeof( arr1 ) / sizeof( *arr1 );
    const size_t N2 = sizeof( arr2 ) / sizeof( *arr2 );
    
    std::vector<int> arr3 = ::merge( arr1, N1, arr2, N2 );
    
    for ( const auto &item : arr3 )
    {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

There is already the standard algorithm `std::merge` that you could use instead of your user-defined function.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {1, 3, 5, 7};
    int arr2[] = {2, 4, 6, 8};
    const size_t N1 = sizeof( arr1 ) / sizeof( *arr1 );
    const size_t N2 = sizeof( arr2 ) / sizeof( *arr2 );
    
    std::vector<int> arr3;
    arr3.reserve( N1 + N2 );
    
    std::merge( arr1, arr1 + N1, arr2, arr2 + N2, std::back_inserter( arr3 ) );
    
    for ( const auto &item : arr3 )
    {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

The standard algorithm also can be called the following way

```
std::merge( std::begin( arr1 ), std::end( arr1 ), 
            std::begin( arr2 ), std::end( arr2 ), 
            std::back_inserter( arr3 ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int arr1size = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
```

You are forgetting an extremely important fact. That is, an array *as a function parameter* is just a pointer (unlike other contexts). The following declarations are identical (and they redeclare the same function).

```
void f(int a[]);
void f(int a[10]);
void f(int* a);
```

I'm afraid, if you're sticking to plain arrays, you will have to pass their size around.

```
void f(int a[], int n);
```

Note that if you pass an array by reference, you do *not* lose size information, but you limit yourself to lvalues of array type (i.e. you can't pass dynamically allocated arrays or slices of a regular array)

```
template <int N>
void f(int (&a)[N]);
```

Alternatively, you could use `std::array<T, N>` or `std::vector<T>`, depending on requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was unsure about the fact that array was a pointer!! Another user had pointed this out as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @Vincent: Please note that an array is a pointer *only* as a funcition by-value parameter. In many many other contexts arrays and pointers are very different

Comment: Don't forget though that `int x[3]; std::cout << sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]) << std::endl;` will actually output `3`, so it's a bit more nuanced than it might first appear.